# Can't get CSS grid to display multiple colums

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is what it currently looks like (I zoomed out a bit to get more in the pic):
[image]

And this is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="popularContainer">
    <div class="popularContent">
        <div class="content-1"> 
            <div class="content-1-container-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi inventore illum voluptatem quod necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt vero aperiam. Iste, voluptas.</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="content-2"> 
            <div class="content-2-container-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi inventore illum voluptatem quod necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt vero aperiam. Iste, voluptas.</p>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="content-3"> 
            <div class="content-3-container-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi inventore illum voluptatem quod necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt vero aperiam. Iste, voluptas.</p>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="content-4">   
            <div class="content-4-container-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi inventore illum voluptatem quod necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt vero aperiam. Iste, voluptas.</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="content-5"> 
            <div class="content-5-container-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi inventore illum voluptatem quod necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt vero aperiam. Iste, voluptas.</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="content-6"> 
            <div class="content-6-container-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi inventore illum voluptatem quod necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt vero aperiam. Iste, voluptas.</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.popularContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, auto));
    grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    gap: 75px 50px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content-1 { 
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    background-color: #30475E;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.content-2 { 
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    background-color: #30475E;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.content-3 { 
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    background-color: #30475E;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.content-4 { 
    order: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    background-color: #30475E;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.content-5 { 
    order: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    background-color: #30475E;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.content-6 { 
    order: 6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    background-color: #30475E;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Also after testing it out some, I suspect that it has something to do with another piece of code so I will link to it here if that helps.

LINK: https://codepen.io/DominickDominick/pen/QWMqjQw

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Because you have applied grid to the container div instead of the content wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The css that you wrote for the class **popularContainer** has to be for the class **popularContent**.

So a short solution is to remove the class:

```
.popularContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, auto));
    grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    gap: 75px 50px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And replace it with the class:

```
.popularContent{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, auto));
    grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    gap: 75px 50px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You didn't apply any css to the parent of content-1/6. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the flex-direction property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction.
You need to remove the **popularContent** div in the html and then add
the following css:

```
.popularContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px,auto));
    grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    gap: 75px 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

flex-direction is set to column by default.